# To find .txt file with specific name and check for some values and mail the values in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to this. i have a folder test which contains many ".txt" files. I want to search a particular file (file_20131211_xxxxx.txt) and in the file, search for the word "exit:x" and mail it to a address as the exit value is x. please help me with this using power shell.

Comment: Can you please show what you already tried, so someone can help you out to understand why things didn't work better?

Comment: i have gone till  $date = get-date -Format "yyyyMMdd" $fname = "file_"$date *.txt Get-ChildItem D:\* -filter $fname | Select-String -Pattern "exit"

Comment: please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Powershell has very good help built in.

Open a fresh Powershell console, and run these commands and read through the output:

```
Get-Help Get-ChildItme -Full
```

This will help you find locate all the .txt files.

```
Get-Help Select-String -Full
```

This will help you locate the words "exit x" in those files.

```
Get-Help Send-MailMessage -full
```

This will help you send the email.